# Squared Sub-Gaussian norm of $u^T X$ is uppder bounded by the second moment of $u^T X$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random-matrices

I have read over some papers which use the following assumption of Sub-Gaussian random vector:

> (Sub-gaussian observations). The random vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^p$ is sub-gaussian, that is $\|X\|_{\psi_2}<\infty$. In addition, there exist a numerical constant $c_1>0$ such that
> $$
> \mathbb{E}(\langle X, u\rangle)^2 \geq c_1\|\langle X, u\rangle\|_{\psi_2}^2, \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^p .
> $$

I go back to read Vershynin's ''Introduction to the non-asymptotic analysis of random
matrices'', and I found the following equivalent characteriszation of Sub-Gaussian random variable:

> 1. Tails: $\mathbb{P}\{|X|>t\} \leq \exp \left(1-t^2 / K_1^2\right)$ for all $t \geq 0$;
> 2. Moments: $\left(\mathbb{E}|X|^p\right)^{1 / p} \leq K_2 \sqrt{p}$ for all $p \geq 1$;
> 3. Super-exponential moment: $\mathbb{E} \exp \left(X^2 / K_3^2\right) \leq e$;
> 4. Moreover, if $\mathbb{E} X=0$ then properties $1-3$ are also equivalent to the following one- Moment generating function: $\mathbb{E} \exp (t X) \leq \exp \left(t^2 K_4^2\right)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

And the definition of Sub-Gaussian random vector:

> (Sub-gaussian random vectors). We say that a random vector $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is sub-gaussian if the one-dimensional marginals $\langle X, x\rangle$ are sub-gaussian random variables for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The sub-gaussian norm of $X$ is defined as
> $$
> \|X\|_{\psi_2}=\sup _{x \in S^{n-1}}\|\langle X, x\rangle\|_{\psi_2}
> $$

However, I still didn't find one that align with the assumption I read in that paper. The second property (Moments) of Sub-Gaussian random variable is similar; however, it is saying the moment is upper bounded by the Sub-Gaussian norm. The assumption I listed on the top is saying the squared Sub-Gaussian norm of $\langle X,u\rangle$ is upper bounded by the second moment of $\langle X,u\rangle$.

May I ask if the assumption on the top applies to any Sub-Gaussian random vector?

I also heard that if $X$ is a random vector, the definition of **marginal Sub-Gaussian random vector** is different from the definition of **joint Sub-Gaussian random vector**. So I'm wondering if my question is associated with the distinction of these two definitions. However, I'm not able to get precise definition of these two types of Sub-Gaussian random vector over the internet. Which one of these two alings with the definition of Sub-Gaussian random vector in Vershynin's ''Introduction to the non-asymptotic analysis of random matrices''?